# CSS Styling of an HTML Table to enforce size restriction

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup some sizing constraints on my HTML table. Basically, I want the tables width to be 70% of the screen, and each table data item should be 25% of the tables width, and the table data height should be 25% of the tables height. For the most part, enforcing the table width was easy, but this is complicated by the fact that my td blocks contain img elements, and some of the images are larger than the others. Is there an easy way to enforce the sizing I want, and then have the img just take up 100% of the td?

Comment: Did you try adding max-width and max-height to the img tag in td? Check this: http://jsbin.com/vuzuqinu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the image's size:

```
max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
td img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuzuqinu/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  table.mytableclass td > img{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
```